# Error in creating RODC

Tags: active-directory, rodc

I have a win server 2012 r2 server named ws7. from my other windows 2012 server that is currently our primary active directory server named ws4 I am trying to create a RODC for a remote office with limited bandwith

I am trying to "pre-create a read only domain account" and when I enter the name of the server it gives me the error"

> The Specified computer name "ws7" already exists in the domain
>   "mydomain.local"

The server ws7 is joined to the domain but i'm not sure what to do next

Comment: From Microsoft: `The server that will become the RODC must not be joined to the domain before you try to attach it to the RODC account`, which means that you should not have already joined the new server to the domain. You have so therefore the computer account already exists.

Comment: is removing it from the domain sufficient or must i delete the computer account as well?

Comment: You'll need to do both. You can't pre-stage the computer account if a computer account already exists. You need the server to not be joined to the domain when you connect it to the pre-staged computer account.

Comment: Is there a better way to cache a few passwords on a file server in a remote temp office other than RODC?

Answer (score 2):

Precreating an account is used only when the object doesn't exist in Active Directory yet. From what you are describing ws7 is a member server of your domain already.

You'll just want to add the roles via the server manager on the new server 'ws7'.